# Can two claims be Logically equivalent and have different truth tables?

Tags: logic

I'm looking for an example that will help me understand better the issue of logical equivalence.

I know that two claims can be logically equivalent and yet have different truth tables.

But while trying to think of an example for this a few questions popped.
What does it mean for two truth tables to be distinct (unequal)?

I think $P \to Q \equiv \lnot P \lor Q$ is a good example of claims which are equivalent, but don't have equivalent truth-tables.

But what about $P \lor Q$ and $Q \lor P$?

Is there a better way to understand this?

Comment: To me, "difference in truth tables" means the rows don't match for corresponding values of the variables.  So I would actually say $P \to Q$ and $\lnot P \lor Q$ have the same truth table, even though they may have differently labeled columns.  Not a logic expert, though.

Comment: How do you know that two claims can be logically equivalent and yet have different truth tables?

Comment: "I know that two claims can be logically equivalent and yet have different truth tables." Um, what?

Comment: The demand was to prove this assumption, so naturally i assumed the question was correct. maybe the meaning in different truth table is different from what i perceived, any way i will seek advice from my professor. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NO. If two statements are logically equivalent, then their columns in the combined truth-table will be exactly the same. Truth-tables are a way of showing the truth-conditions of statements, and two statements are equivalent if and only if they have the same truth-conditions ... i.e. have the same truth-table!

By 'combined truth-table I mean that both statements would be put in the same truth-table. Because if you don't do that, then superficially it may look like the truth-tables of, for example, $P$ and $P \land (P \lor Q)$ are not the same:

$\begin{array}{c|c}
P&P\\
\hline
T&T\\
F&F\\
\end{array}$

$\begin{array}{cc|c}
P&Q&P\land (P \lor Q)\\
\hline
T&T&T\\
T&F&T\\
F&T&F\\
F&F&F\\
\end{array}$

But using a combined truth-table:

$\begin{array}{cc|c|c}
P&Q&P&P \land (P \lor Q)\\
\hline
T&T&T&T\\
T&F&T&T\\
F&T&F&F\\
F&F&F&F\\
\end{array}$

Comment: .. why the downvote? ....  it seems I answered the question the the OP's satisfaction .... why do I keep getting these anonymous downvotes?

Comment: Note, you could have easily listed, in the truth table for $P$ a column for the truth value assignments of two variables, P and Q, in addition to the rightmost column below P, from which when $P$ is true, the third column P is true, when P is false, the third column P is false.  No need to create a combined truth table to see their equivalence.  $P=T, Q= T: P = T;  P= T, Q = F: P= T; P = F, Q = T: P = F; P=F, Q= F: P = F.  So long as the truth value assignments of the two variables of two claims are equivalent, and the right-most column for each column mach, they are equivalent.

Comment: @amWhy That would work as well, sure. But the point I was making is that you need to take *some* care to find that they are equivalent; if one is not careful, one might think they are not.

Answer (score 4):

No.  In fact, what is true is that  two claims have equivalent truth-tables if and only if they are equivalent. And two statements are not logically equivalent if and only if they do not have equivalent truth-tables.

You claim that $P\to Q \equiv \lnot P \lor Q$ is an example in which the two statements are logically equivalent, but do not  have equivalent truth-tables. Let's explore that:

\begin{array}{cc|c}
P&Q|&P\to Q\\
\hline
T&T&T\\
T&F&F\\
F&T&T\\
F&F&T\\
\end{array}

\begin{array}{cc|c}
P&Q&\lnot P \lor Q\\
\hline
T&T&T\\
T&F&F\\
F&T&T\\
F&F&T\\
\end{array}

Of course, we could have written $\lnot P \lor Q$ using the following truth-table:

\begin{array}{cc|c|c}
P&Q&\lnot P& \lnot P \lor Q\\
\hline
T&T&F&T\\
T&F&F&F\\
F&T&F&T\\
F&F&T&T\\
\end{array}

While we used the extra column for the last claim, we could put $\lnot P$ as a separate column in the first claim, e.g.:

\begin{array}{\color{blue}{cc}|c|c}
P&Q&\lnot P&P\to Q\\
\hline
T&T&F&T\\
T&F&F&F\\
F&T&T&T\\
F&F&T&F\\
\end{array}

In any case the **two truth-tables are equivalent when under the same truth-value assignment of variables, the right-most columns (under each claim) are identical.**

---

$P\lor Q \equiv Q\lor P$, and we know that for the simple fact that $\lor$ is commutative.

And indeed, their truth tables also reveals they are equivalent (i.e., proves the top statement), meaning that the right-most columns (with the header $P\lor Q$, $Q\lor P$, respectively), evaluate to the same truth value under the same truth value assignments to the variables $P, Q$.

E.g
\begin{array}{cc|c}
P&Q&P\lor Q\\
\hline
T&T&T\\
T&F&T\\
F&T&T\\
F&F&F\\
\end{array}

\begin{array}{cc|c}
P&Q&Q\lor P\\
\hline
T&T&T\\
T&F&T\\
F&T&T\\
F&F&F\\
\end{array}